# Android Studio is full of errors

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest, manifest

Okay, so I can't develop nothing as my Android Studio decided to.
My all project is full of errors, unknown errors caused by Android Studio.

note: my files are correct, it is an other problem because even if I will import something from google codes it will have errors.

When I import a project everything's fine, but then after indexing and such things, all sudden everything is red and shouldn't be.

My errors for example are :

```
 button1.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener()

{
 .... 
  ....
}
```

Well shouldn't be error but : `cannot resolve symbol setOnLongClickListener`

Another example:

```
    button1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

I used this exact code for other button, seems right, I always using this line, it was fine until my Android Studio decided to give me some hard time, this line is full by errors and they are:

```
Unknown class: 'button1' , invalid method declaration; return type required, missing method body, or declare abstract
```

and there are like 20 errors that shouldn't be, things I tried:

1. deleting iml files , .idea folder - worked for a while but now it happened again and it doesn't fix it.
2. reinstalling android studio and then importing project.
3. upgrading android studio version to 1.3
4. restarting my pc.
5. importing project to an other pc, happened after a while.
6. Invalidate caches/ restart.
7. Changing module in project structure - I changed it back to how it was (it didn't help) and I think it caused the manifest error down..

My Module:app build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "firstappdevelopments.david.reactiontime"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
     }
}

  dependencies {
     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    }
```

Also I noticed now, my Manifest file as an error in `android:name=".MainActivity"` says it has no default structure. something like this. here is the full normal code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

</manifest>
```

Please, if someone knows what is the problem or what can I else do, just say, and I am sorry about my English, thank you all.

Comment: Take a deep look into your `.xml` files. Some of them may contain errors.

Comment: @Holmes I have only one xml file, I didn't add nothing to it when it suddenly happened , it was and now the same file, 2 buttons, textview and listview, it actually looks good, do you want me to edit and add the file?

Comment: ... wasn't it better keeping using Eclipse?

Comment: @DerGol...lum It's a new computer.. Eclipse is so much better!!!

Comment: I know. That's why I didn't switch... ;)

Comment: @DerGol...lum But soon you will have to.. it is the supported ide for android by google..

Comment: Did you import the Project from Eclipse ? Do you have Gradle structure of Project in Android Studio after importing. What's your c:\ProjectsFolder\yourProject\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: `But soon you will have to.` I will **not**. W la resistance!!

Comment: So after importing/creating the new project in Android Studio -> can you at least compile from command line? Go to your project's root folder and type "gradlew assembleDebug". Gradlew is a wrapper around Gradle that does not require you to have Gradle installed when you start running it (it will download the right version on the fly the first time you run it). It might be a case where you don't have the right dependencies to your project and maybe Android Studio can't figure it out.

Comment: The closing and opening of project fixed my issue. I had exactly the same issue that you described. HELL this tool is. Eclipse runs for months without restarting, and this tool is developed by amateurs, focus only on features not stability.

Answer (score 14):

What I've seen is my code is full of errors, but it still builds fine and deploys fine to the device.

**To fix it:**

- click on FILE > INVALIDATE CACHES / RESTART
- Then close the project
- Re open the project

[image]

Comment: another thing I've had to do was delete the `.gradle` and `.idea` folders within the project after closing the project. When you open the project again Android Studio shows that stuff is wrong and fixes it.

Comment: Invalidate Caches / Restart, and deleting .gradle & .idea folders worked for me

Comment: I've found this solution works really well after Android Studio "breaks" the project when switching branches in git (or, just now after a git commit - LOL!)

Comment: It works for me well. but happening many time for me. I'm nervous about that.

Answer (score 1):

For me I upgraded my Kotlin Version from 1.4 to 1.5.0 and it is now working.

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'
    classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$navigationVersion"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.0"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

Afterwards I did a clean and a Rebuild and everything worked fine thereafter.